# Does Euler's Theorem for homogeneous functions require continuous differentiability?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Euler's Theorem for homogeneous functions states that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is homogeneous of degree $k$ ($f(cx) = c^k f(x)$ for all $c > 0$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$), if and only if the partial derivatives of $f$ satisfy
$$
k f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i}
$$
Clearly this theorem requires differentiability of $f$. However, it seems to often be stated with the requirement of *continuous* differentiability, e.g., [here](https://www.usna.edu/Users/math/meh/homog.pdf). On the other hand, it is also sometimes stated without this requirement, and I don't see how any of the proofs actually use continuity of partial derivatives (e.g., the proof [here](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~kcborder/Notes/EulerHomogeneity.pdf)).

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could clear this up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to assume continuous differentiability. In fact, the result can be proved point-wise, as follows.

Fix a point $x$ where $f$ is differentiable. Consider the function $g(c)=f(cx)$.

Homogeneity implies that if $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then it is differentiable at $tx$ for every $t\neq 0$, because
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(tx+h)-f(tx)&=&t^k(f(x+h/t)-f(x))\\
&=&t^{k}(f'(x)(h/t)+o(\|h\|_2/t))\\
&=&t^{k-1}f'(x)(h)+t^ko(\|h\|_2/t)\\
\end{eqnarray*}
so that $f'(tx)=t^{k-1}f'(x)$ for every $t\neq 0$. The notation $f'(x)(w)$ in this context means the dot product between the gradient of $f$ at $x$ and the vector $w$.

It follows that $g$ is differentiable at every $c\neq 0$, and by the chain rule, 
$$g'(c)=f'(cx)(x)=c^{k-1}f'(x)(x)$$
On the other hand, since $g(c)=f(cx)=c^{k}f(x)$, direct differentiation gives
$g'(c)=kc^{k-1}f(x)$, and we deduce the announced formula, $kf(x)=f'(x)(x)$.

All we needed was the chain-rule, which does not require continuous derivatives.